# Direction of propogation of a EMW

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, waves, electromagnetic-radiation

If let say i have an EMW given by- (Note the difference between $k$ and K)

B(x,y,z)=$B_0sin[(x+y)\frac{K}{√2}+wt]\hat k$

i got confused in 2 different outcomes when i wanted to find out the direction of propogation of the wave.

**Case 1**
-Since direction of propogation always points towards the wave vector K its should be $\frac{\hat i}{√2}+\frac{\hat j}{√2}$

**Case 2** - Comparing the B(x,y,z) equation with the general equation for emw we know if coefficients of Kr and wt are same then wave propogates in negative r direction, here i got confused and dont  know how to progress and find direction of r.

Comment: If you look at the derivation *why* a wave would propagate along the direction of the wave vector  ${\bf k}$ you might see how this works out for this situation.

Comment: I know K is defined as K= w/v where v is velocity of wave thus direction of wave velocity is direction of K. But i am confused about 'r' how am i supposed to find direction of r in this situation

Comment: Maybe look at this earlier question: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/376359/are-there-two-ways-of-representing-a-wave-travelling-towards-positive-x-direct?rq=1

Comment: The moderations want you to reformulate the question. Maybe you give some background of where you got the equation from.

Answer (score 2):

I assume K is a scalar value.
The wave that is described by the above formular:

Describes a $\vec{B}$ filed that is always oriented in the $\vec{k}$ direction.

The wave propagation can only be in along $\vec{e_x}+\vec{e_y}$ direction. With a postive K it would be in the $-(\vec{e_x}+\vec{e_y}) $ direction with a wavelength of $\lambda=\frac{2\pi}{K}$.

Comment: Well yes. But the field described by the equation describes a different field. The equations lets you calculate the field in every place in space and on each time. A field like this might be an approximation of a field in a limited place. E.g. Near some antenna.

Comment: If $\hat{k}$ is an arbitrary vector then that could still be be perpendicular to the direction of propagation. Since the original posting used $\hat{i}$ synonymus for $\vec{x}$ then k would  mean z direction an be  perpendicular...

Comment: Whoops, my mistake. It *is* transverse. I’ll delete my comments. And I’ve upvoted your answer.

Comment: @mond i am not familiar with variable 'e' that you used in answer. What does it mean?

Comment: $\vec{e_x}$ would be the unit vector in the x direction. I think you used $\hat{i}$ instead. It is a matter of different tastes. I switched to using these more explicit form as in your original posting there is some ambiguity about all that. And then we electrical engineer have the symbol i reserved for the current (even to the point where we write the complex unit as j instead).